# Android ImageView in ScrollView shows white screen

Tags: android, imageview, scrollview

I want to show an `image` which is **longer** than the screen.

I'm using an `ImageView` inside a `scroll view`. I get a **white screen**, which is **scrollable** to the `height` of the `image`, but the image itself is **not presented**.

**Here's the layout xml I'm using**:-

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:contentDescription="@string/test_image_content_description"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:src="@drawable/test_image" />

</ScrollView>
```

**test_image.png** is a file which is available in all the "`drawable`" folders of the **application**.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: is it getting dispalyed in your graphical layout?

Comment: Hi, yes. It is visible in the graphical layout as I would want it to look when it actually runs.

Answer (score 0):

In your `ScrollView`,

Change `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` to `android:layout_height="math_parent"`

Comment: @dcoder it can be because ImageView scales image. You can try to change scaleType of your ImageView to "fitXY", or replace ImageView with View, and set your image as background.

Answer (score 0):

you can add a scaletype to your imageview, like use `android:scaleType="center"` to center image with no scale, and then you should remove the code `android:adjustViewBounds="true"` from imageview. Please see `ImageView.ScaleType` for details. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found the problem. It seems that the problem was that the image had height of 6000 pixels, and the max size Android is willing to display (even inside ScrollView) is of 4096 (even if I add scaling).

After resizing the image, it is shown without a problem.

Thank you all for the replies!

Comment: where did you find the limit number height **4096**.I found it shows on some large size screen ,whereas can't display in small size.